# How to scan QR Code in Windows Phone 8.1 using Phonegap/Cordova/WinJS/HTML/CSS/JS?

Tags: windows, cordova, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, zxing

I am using [ZXing.Net](https://zxingnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest) library to scan/read QR codes from camera in Windows Phone 8.1. I went through this sample: https://github.com/wildabeast/BarcodeScanner. But this is for Windows Phone 8.0 Silverlight apps which uses following namespaces:

```
using Microsoft.Phone.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
```

These namespaces are not available in **Windows Phone 8.1** as my project is targeted to Windows Phone 8.1.
Is there any other plugins to solve this problem in HTML/JS/WinJS/Cordova?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can follow this post [Vinicius Linck](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/20140610201847-102625795-windows-8-store-apps-javascript-and-barcode-scanner). Hope this might help. This github repo really helped me lot.
https://github.com/vinnylinck/CordovaW8BarcodeDemo

Comment: Let me know if you got stuck.

Comment: Sure! I'm going through this. https://github.com/vinnylinck/CordovaW8BarcodeDemo/blob/master/platforms/windows8/www/plugins/com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner/src/windows8/CameraHandler.js